# dropDownList в форме меняет имя поля

Tags: yii2

Делаю в форме добавления пользователя выбор пола использую dropdownlist.
Непонятно почему, но дроп.даун меняет имя поля. Вот так вставляю в форму:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'sex')->dropDownList(
    [0 => 'мужской', 1 => 'женский']
    )->label('Пол') ?>
```

По идее, после отправки формы, я должен получить переменную $_POST["sex"], но посмотрев в отладчик я вижу следуущее:

```
<select id="star_user-sex" class="form-control" name="star_user[sex]">
<option value="0" selected="">мужской</option>
<option value="1">женский</option>
</select>
```

Откуда берется star_user-sex?

Comment: Как вы форму назовете так она и поплывет (с) У вас форма имеет id = star_user. Этот идентификатор добавляется автоматически ко всем полям формы. И с руководства форм Yii2 - Если в форме только одна модель, и вы хотите упростить имена полей ввода, то можете сделать это, переопределив метод formName() модели так, чтобы он возвращал пустую строку.

Comment: спасибо, а как распознать поле  вот что это star_user[sex]
например поле sex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доброе утро.

Никогда не обращайтесь в yii2 напрямую с глобальным массивам. Для этого есть специальные методы

```
Yii::$app->request->get();
Yii::$app->request->post();
```

И ещё всяко-разно полезных штук.
А название складывается из названия модели и имени атрибута. Всё просто, это нормальное поведение.

Comment: Спасибо slo_nik, за полит.информацию!

Comment: пожалуйста. Вот в продолжение полит.информации https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/tree/master/docs/guide-ru ))))